# Web3j generate command not running

Tags: solidity, web3j, solc, solcjs

I am trying to generate a java wrapper class for a solidity contract, I have compiled the file and have the abi and bin file, but when I run the command as follows:

````
web3j solidity generate PR_sol_ballot.bin PR_sol_ballot.abi -o .\Web3App\src\main\java -p com.project.contracts
``` I get an error saying "unmatched arguments from index 2" I have tried searching this but can't find anything that clearly explains what this error is or how to fix it. I am using web3j version 1.4.0 and the compiler is solidity v 0.5.0 (solc-js)
````

Answer (score 2):

The syntax has changed. Try commands like this:

```
web3j generate solidity -a PR_sol_ballot.abi -b PR_sol_ballot.bin -o .\Web3App\src\main\java -p com.project.contracts
```

See also: [web3j](https://docs.web3j.io/latest/smart_contracts/construction_and_deployment/#solidity-smart-contract-wrappers)